# ASP.NET Core recursive function to show table with multiple child rows

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a table that has ID, Name, ParentId.
So basically, for example I could have those entries inside database table –

[How table structure actually looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCBAE.png)

And what I need to do is create a table that will have nested rows and display child(s) on expand

1. Name1

   - Name2

     - Name5
   - Name3

     - Name4
2. Name7

   - Name6

But there could be more nesting than just 3. So I would need to use some kind of recursive function inside view. Currently I’ve been using this code

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var entity in Model)
    {
        if (entity.ParentId == null)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><button class="expandButton" type="button" ></button></td>
                <td>
                    @entity.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="ManipulateEntity" asp-route-id="@entity.Id">Manipulate</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            int child = 1;
            foreach (var childEntity in Model.Where(i => i.ParentId == entity.Id))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @childEntity.Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="ManipulateEntity" asp-route-id="@childEntity.Id">Manipulate</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                child++;
            }
        }
    }
```

But unfortunately, this shows results only for the first parent and his childs, when there are childs of childs, it bumps out and shows just for the first parent and his childs. As you can see, I am iterating through Model which is basically List

How can this be done on View side? I’ve provided minimum code to understand my current logic, which as I’ve said just shows first parent and his childs, but I am unable to figure it out on my own what should I change to make this work.

Comment: Do you need to implement it using only razor pages and no 3rd parties?

Comment: No 3rd parties. Well I would do it in View, since I have it all there, all the information needed. I have parent ID of each of the inputs inside Db table, so I guess I just need a way to do it through some way of recursive function inside the view. Probably someone had the same issues and can share the solution.

Comment: Have you tried jstree?

Comment: No, but I don't see how it would help me. Also, jstree is a jquery plugin, and I certainly can't use it. As I understand jstree helps you create tree using the right markup, which is not a problem in this question. Here you don't know how many and which one of nodes has child(s) and if their child has their own childs.. So you need to do recursive function in order to make it right. The problem of mark up is least on my mind since all of them will be rows, and probably would just add #number to parent, and .1 to child and .1.1 to the child of child... So I don't really think jstree is any help